# log4j classes not found in Netbeans IDE

Tags: java, netbeans, log4j, classnotfound

I am working through Tim Downey's book "Web Development with Java".

In chapter 4 one of the topics is logging with log4j.

In order to initialise the logger an initialisation servlet is used.

One of the classes needed is, e.g., "FileAppender". Hence, there is an import statement at the top of the file for it:

```
import org.apache.log4j.FileAppender;
```

I also used the same import statement. However, netbeans is telling me that this class doesn't exist. (The same is true for any other class from the log4j library.)

Normally, when I create an object of a class I have not yet imported, the netbeans IDE offers me to import the respective class.

So I created an object of type "FileAppender":

```
FileAppender appender = getAppender(logPath);
```

... I hoped that the IDE would tell me what import-statement to use in order to import this class.

However, no such luck. Apparently, the IDE does not know about such a class.

So, I think that for some reason the IDE does not know where to look. 
This again means that I probably did something wrong when setting log4j up.

Here's what I did:

1. I downloaded log4j from the apache website.
2. I copied the downloaded file (apache-log4j-2.8.2-bin.tar) in a folder on my desktop.
3. I used Archive Utility to extract the content of the tar file.
4. As a result of step 4 I then had a folder called "apache-log4j-2.8.2-bin" in the same folder where the tar file is located.
5. I went to netbeans IDE and followed the steps in this video to add log4j to netbeans: 
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vqhQY7U9Rlc (I called the new library "log4j")
6. As a result of step 5, I now have an additional library named "log4j" in my Libraries-Folder

But the IDE doesn't seem to know about any log4j packages or classes.

Did I do anything wrong? (What did I do wrong?)

************************UPDATE***************************************

Here's a screenshot of the netbeans library folder after I added log4j:

[image]

Here's a picture of the IDE telling me it doesn't know about log4j's package
(What you see is the upper part of the file "InitLog4j.java", which again is inside the package named "various". Package "various" is inside the folder named "Source Packages"):

[image]

***********************UPDATE2***************************************

The problem exists independent of whether I include log4j as library or as JAR/FOLDER.

After adding log4j as Jar/Folder:

[image]

... my netbeans folder structure looks as follows (log4j is in the folder whose path starts with "/Users"):

[image]

However, the problem remains the same. Netbeans doesn't know about log4j packages.

**********************UPDATE3***********************************

I found the FileAppender class among the many files inside the log4j folder:

[image]

So, the class "FileAppender" exists. Hence, when I create an object of type "FileAppender", the Idea should offer to import the class. However, this does not happen (in the screenshot above you can see that the class "FileAppender" exists (see left side), you can also see that the IDE does not recognise the class (see code on the right side)).

*************************UPDATE4***********************************

Instead of adding the whole folder, I now only added the jar files inside the folder. The netbeans folder structure now looks as follows:

[image]

However, the IDE still does not seem to recognise the log4j packages (e.g. for the FileAppender object no import statement is suggested).

Comment: did you added this jar to library ?

Comment: which jar to which library?

Comment: huh. Really ?? How would your class know which class ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean ... I added the whole log4j library to the Libraries Folder in netbeans ...

Comment: Yes, that was what I asking. I'm not sure, if you have mentioned this in your question as it was so lengthy. You need to be very clear and precise with your question. Otherwise, nobody will read your question

Comment: Can you put the screen of your project by expanding library and the class file where you are getting error

Comment: I added 2 screenshots

Comment: Nope, you haven't added the jar right. You can see the difference between my project and yours. I think, you are selecting folder. **You need to select jar file while adding it not the folder.**

Comment: I used "Add Jar/Folder" (see new screenshot) .. after that I do not have an option any more to choose either Jar or Folder

Comment: Please go through my updated answer. It will ask you to navigate. right ?

Comment: Please confirm, if your problem solved

Comment: my Library folder now looks as in your screenshot (i.e. I included only the jar files without the folder containing them). But the IDE still doesn't seem to know about the log4j packages ...

Comment: You aren't selecting correct jar. Look for the jar, which contains the word `log4j` and version. Not the one, which says api, doc. You can refer my screenshot.

Comment: I searched through the jar files and found the class "FileAppender" ... I then wrote down the name of the package inside which I had found the "FileAppender" class. Then I wrote an import statement (import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender;) ... that worked.

Comment: But why didn't netscape suggest an import statement for me (as it usually does) ?.... Searching through all the jar-files to find the classes I want to import is extremely cumbersome

Comment: Is it because it's an external library?

Comment: I don't think. If your jar is part of project. Then, it should have asked you to import. May be you have added the jar but didn't clean-build.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your screenshot. It seems like you have added this jar as library. You need to add the jar using `Add Jar/Folder..` option **not the** `Add Library..`

[image]

It will prompt window to navigate and select your jar.

[image]

Once, you add them, then it should look like

[image]

You can expand the jar from here and see, if required class exists inside the jar or not.

**==Update==**

You need to select only `*.jar` file not the complete folder. As shown below.

[image]